# I need to run a new version of code that adds edges between entities in CluedIn

Tags: cluedin

I have run a crawler on my local Docker instance and it created many entities with no connecting edges, which was expected and by design. I then added code to one of the clue producers to add edges to that clue, and deployed the new code to the same CluedIn instance. But after crawling with the new code the resulting clue is not merged with the existing entity and the edges are not created. I need to understand how to incrementally make this kind of upgrade to an existing deployment.

Is this by design?

The entity codes are 100% the same, so I don't know why it is not merging.

Sincerely,
~Stan

Answer (score 0):

During the new clues processing, CluedIn checks clue hashes and skips the clues if a clue with a given hash is already processed.

The reference data is part of a clue and when you create a reference, the clue hash changes.

You can see it in the debugger when in a clue producer, you have a code like:

```cs
                // (Name Basic)-[:KnownFor]->(Title)
                _factory.CreateOutgoingEntityReference(clue, IMDbConstants.EntityTypes.TitleBasic,
                    IMDbConstants.EntityEdgeTypes.KnownFor, input, title);
```

If you check the clue hash before and after this line (`BitConverter.ToString(clue.ComputeHash())`), you will see that the values are different.

Based on that, I suspect that either the new code was not deployed, or the new clue producer doesn't add the reference.

I would add extra logging to the clue producer to ensure that it adds these references.